# Worksheet_Change Never FIres

Tags: events, vba, excel

I am using VBA to alter Excel and have the following simple event handler inside the Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "HI"
End Sub
```

This never fires though, ever. I have tested in the Immediate Window:

> ?Application.EnableEvents

which ultimately returns True, so it should fire. Does anyone know why this doesn't want to fire at all?

Comment: Stupid questions: is the code in Sheet1 and not in a module? Is it in the right Sheet1 (say you have 2 workbooks open and both have a Sheet1)?

Comment: Also, what are you doing that you expect the event to fire?

Comment: There is only one WorkBook and yes it is in Sheet1 and we are working in Sheet1. I do have code in a Module and those Subs work fine. - I have a column where I want people to enter the Refresh Rate for RTD.ThrottleInterval, so that way the user can alter how fast Excel refreshes from the RTD

Comment: I tested the above code and it works fine. How is the change happening in the cell? Manually or by formula?

Comment: Manually, since that event should fire for any change, I just have been typing in random cells and hitting enter, yet nothing happens.

Comment: I found my problem though. If debugger pops an error and you say debug, events wont work until you stop debugging

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have more than one sheet?  Be aware that the sheet's CodeName property and the Name property (the name on the tab in Excel) aren't always the same.  For instance, if the Project Explorer lists

```
Sheet2 (Sheet1)
```

Then Sheet1 is the Name and Sheet2 is the CodeName.

The easiest way to see if you have put the code in the wrong module is to right click on the sheet's tab and choose View Code.  That will bring up the CodePane for that sheet and that's where your code should be.

Comment: Your way worked, it seems, and I do not know how, but I had the following:

Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3
Sheet4 (Sheet 1)
...

And so I just tested the "Sheet4 (Sheet1)" and it worked, whereas before I was just testing in Sheet1

Answer (score 4):

This question was posted a long time ago, but I recently had this same problem. If there are any other vba newbies out there struggling with this, try saving your workbook and re-opening it. After I did that, the Worksheet_Change Sub in my sheet fired as I expected.

Perhaps there is a control to compile worksheet subs that I was missing???

Comment: I fount the problem though. If debugger pops an error and you say debug, events wont work until you stop debugging.

Comment: In 2018 this is still a bug in Excel. No other solution worked, but I had to close Excel and re-open my workbook. Voila!

Answer (score 2):

Usually used with `Target`. Here's an example if you highlight M4 and change the value see what happens:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Address = "$M$4" Then
    MsgBox ("HI")
 End If
End Sub
```

[HERE](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=148634) is quite a nice posting about this event

Adapting code from that post you can then do things like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("$A$1:$V$100")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then 
        MsgBox ("A1")
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$A$2" Then 
        MsgBox ("A2")
    End If 
End Sub
```

Ok - see comments below + I've just tested and your code should actually work. Try this? Does this also not work?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Cells) Then
        MsgBox ("A1")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No that is not true :) If you want to show just a messagebox then change to any cell should fire the messagebox

Comment: ok - just tested the OPers code on my machine and you're correct - target is not required; weird!